# Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined phonegap + Angularjs +google.maps

Tags: android, google-maps, angularjs, cordova, geolocation

Hy every one,

i'm trying to get my angular app to work with phonegap but i already fail with loading the google maps API.

There are no problems in the Browser but deployed to my android phone i get this error from eclipse

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined at file:///android_asset/www/js/controllers.js:20
....
$scope.geolocationAvialable = navigator.geolocation ? true : false;
      if ($scope.geolocationAvialable) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
              var currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
....
```

I would guess cordova is fired before google.maps is loaded!
But who can i make cordova wait for it to be loaded?

many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you call google before it's loaded.
I think you better use the google map module of AngularJs itself:
[this](http://www.directiv.es/angular-google-maps) is a simple working example.